# Preference Menu on 10 inch tablet

Tags: android, menu, tablet, preference

I am trying to figure out why the layout of my Preference menu is displayed in a false way on 10' tablets when using it in landscape mode. It looks like the lines that are to the right of the Checkboxes are actually to the left of them. You can see this here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/109/schnappschuss2013052109.png/

On 7' tablets, everything works like expected to do.

My menu looks like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_message"
        android:key="pref_key_message_settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_key_add_timestamp"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_addTimestamp"
            android:title="@string/pref_addTimestamp"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
        <ListPreference
            android:dependency="pref_key_add_timestamp"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_timestamp_option"
            android:key="pref_key_timestamp_option"
            android:title="@string/pref_timestampOption"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_timestampOptionDialog"
            android:entries="@array/pref_timestampArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_timestampValues"
            android:defaultValue="Time" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_key_add_newline"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_addNewLine"
            android:title="@string/pref_addNewLine"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
        <ListPreference
            android:dependency="pref_key_add_newline"
            android:key="pref_key_newline_option"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_newline_option"
            android:title="@string/pref_newLineOption"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_newLineOptionDialog"
            android:entries="@array/pref_newLineArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_newLineValues"
            android:defaultValue="LF" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_key_clear_text"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_clearText"
            android:title="@string/pref_clearText"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
 <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_storage"
        android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_key_change_name"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_editFilename"
            android:title="@string/pref_editFilename"
            android:defaultValue="history"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_key_add_date"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_addDate"
            android:title="@string/pref_addDate"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_key_add_time"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_addTime"
            android:title="@string/pref_addTime"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>     
       <at.rtcmanager.ConfirmPreference
           android:key="pref_key_clear_history"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_clearHistory"
            android:title="@string/pref_clearHistory"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_time"
        android:key="pref_key_time_settings">  
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_key_autosend_time"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_austosendTime"
            android:title="@string/pref_autosendTime"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <ListPreference
            android:key="pref_key_mode_sentTime"
            android:title="@string/pref_mode_sentTime"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_mode_sentTime"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_modeSentTimeDialog"
            android:entries="@array/pref_sentTimeModeArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_sentTimeValues"
            android:defaultValue="10Byte" />
</PreferenceCategory> 
<PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_about"
        android:key="pref_key_settings_about">  
        <Preference android:title="@string/prefs_about_app" >
            <intent android:action="AboutActivity"/>
        </Preference>

</PreferenceCategory>  
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and is loded with:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsMenuFragment())
                .commit();



    }

    public static class SettingsMenuFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_prefs);

        }

    }
```

Comment: were you able to fix this probllem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution is to extend `SettingsActivity` from usual `Activity`, not from `PreferenceActivity`. But `SettingsFragment` should extend `PreferenceFragment` of course. It helped me, hope this solves your issue too.