# Preferences Screen Background Issue Android

Tags: android, xml, preferenceactivity

I have a preference screen in my app, that only has one item. The screen is displaying fine in all devices, but when i view it on 10inch tablets.. I see a background for the screen. Please refer to the image...

I am not adding any background to the layout.. Not sure why it is appearing.

[image]

Settings.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/generalSettings" />

    <EditTextPreference 
        android:title="@string/distance_title"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:summary="@string/distance_text"
        android:key="@string/distance_key"
        android:defaultValue="5"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Let me know, if you need any other info.

**[EDIT]**

Here is the java code for Settings:

```
@TargetApi(11)
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements
        OnPreferenceClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        init();
        findPreference(Const.Prefs.DISTANCE_KEY).setOnPreferenceClickListener(
                this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        return false;
    }

    private void init() {

        // Fix PreferenceFragment's padding...

        final DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem()
                .getDisplayMetrics();

        float scale = metrics.density;

        int paddingSize = 0;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
            paddingSize = (int) (-32 * scale);
        } else {
            paddingSize = (int) (-16 * scale);
        }

        final View v = getView();

        v.setPadding(paddingSize, 0, paddingSize, 0);

    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

I moved init() to onActivityCreated(), but still i see the padding. Below is the current code. Also find the latest screenshot.

```
@TargetApi(11)
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements
        OnPreferenceClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        findPreference(Const.Prefs.DISTANCE_KEY).setOnPreferenceClickListener(
                this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        return false;
    }


    private void init() {

        // Fix PreferenceFragment's padding...

        final DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem()
                .getDisplayMetrics();

        float scale = metrics.density;

        int paddingSize = 0;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
            paddingSize = (int) (-32 * scale);
        } else {
            paddingSize = (int) (-16 * scale);
        }

        final View v = getView();
        v.setPadding(paddingSize, 0, paddingSize, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        init();

    }

}
```

Updated Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running it to see the output? The layout preview and actual layout are not always the same visually

Comment: @Doomsknight, Yeah, the image is from the output itself..

Comment: Oh sorry, you've drawn boxes to hide info. Fair enough, at glance it looked like a preview :D It seems a bit odd why the line goes through "settings"

Answer (score 1):

Padding occurs also on Android phone devices from 4.0+. I use to set some negative padding.

This is my fix while loading my PreferenceFragment:

```
// Fix PreferenceFragment's padding...
int paddingSize = 0;
if (CLS_Utils.Build_Version < 14)
{
    paddingSize = (int) (-32 * CLS_Gfx.scale);
}
else
{
    paddingSize = (int) (-16 * CLS_Gfx.scale);
}

final View v = getView();

v.setPadding(paddingSize, 0, paddingSize, 0);
```

I put this code in a method called init(), which in turn is called after the line

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
```

**[EDIT]**

Sorry! I didn't edit my living code...

CLS_Gfx is a class where I define my graphics stuff... so CLS_Utils is another
one where I define other variables and methods of public utility.

This is to replace CLS_Gfx.scale:

```
final DisplayMetrics metrics =
    Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();

float scale = metrics.density;
```

**[EDIT]**

This is to replace CLS_Utils.BuildVersion:

```
final int Build_Version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

**[EDIT]**

Being a Fragment, it behaves in a different way than an Activity.
So, this code is not residing in the onCreate() function (the view might still being created).
Personally, I put my code in my **onResume()** method (because I reload the Preferences in case of an update to the language settings, so to refresh all the strings to the new language).
Other good (and more common) places where to move your code: **onCreateView()** or **onActivityCreated()**

Comment: Oh ok, but the padding doesn't appear in Nexus 7 with 4.3? Any ideas?

Comment: also, can you let me know, what CLS_Gfx means?

Comment: See my edited answer... I forgot to remove the references to the classes my project is using! ;)

Comment: Okie.. thanks, Let me test the code and will get back to you. Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: when i run the code, i get a NullPointerException at v.setPadding(paddingSize, 0, paddingSize, 0); The View seems to be null?

Comment: I have added my code to the question.. Please have a look at it and let me know if i am calling init() correctly?

Comment: I'd move it as last instruction. Also, I'd not use onCreate(), since **the view might not yet have been built** at that moment. I have my code in my **onResume()**. Other places where to move your code: **onCreateView()** or **onActivityCreated()**

Comment: I added the existing code and updated screenshot. Please have a look at it. Thanks for your time...

Comment: hmmmm.... maybe you have sime styles set. Even "not explicit" ones. Try having a look in your res values folders. Search in dimens.xml. You could find a horrible **<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">128dp</dimen>**, for instance... comment it out.

Comment: Yeah, i guess the dimens.xml, might be the reason. Will get back to you soon. Thanks...

Comment: This didn't solve the problem either. But really thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: My last guess is: remove styles.xml from values-v11 and values-v14. possibly use your own style. Then, you should solve it, in the end...

Comment: Thanks for the post Frank N. Stein. I was able to removing this padding on an Android Wear app, where space is super important.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to extend from Activity and not from PreferenceActivity. The Fragment should extend from PreferenceFragment of course.

[Preference Menu on 10 inch tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665115/preference-menu-on-10-inch-tablet)